# Correct way to determine the (%) contribution of an independent variable to a MLR model

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, importance

Is the following methodology correct:

1. Fit a multiple linear regression model
2. Obtain the standardized coefficients
3. Sum up the absolute value of all standardized coefficients
4. Divide each individual standardized coefficient estimate by the sum (step 3 above) and multiply by 100 to obtain the % contribution of each predictor variable

If this is incorrect, what is the best way to determine the relative importance of each predictor? In reading other posts, I've found Kruskal's key driver analysis to be one suggestion.....

Comment: If it were that simple, there’d be no need to study confounders, suppressors, mediators, moderators, collinearity, partial or semipartial correlation,.....

Answer (score 1):

One method you might consider is [dominance analysis](http://psycnet.apa.org/buy/1994-08167-001) or [relative weights](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/S15327906MBR3501_1) analysis as an alternative.

The method is implemented for linear regression in many popular packages including [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html), [Stata](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457629.html), and [SAS](http://people.uwm.edu/azen/damacros/).  It will produce a decomposition of the R-square for the model, which can be expressed as a percentage of the R-square explained by each predictor.

In addition, there is a fully online version of relative weights that you could use via [Davidson College](http://relativeimportance.davidson.edu/) routed through R.

Give some of these articles a look - they seem to meet the criteria you're looking for in determining importance here.