# How can I find maximum source of variation in a linear relationship?

Tags: r, regression

Probably very basic for most of you, but I am just starting out in statistics so please pardon my ignorance.

I have a significant positive relationship between body mass (Y) and elevation (X).

I want to find out which component of body mass (i.e. body length or thorax width) is contributing more to the slope (m) of the relationship.

I modeled body size as {1/3 * pi * r^2 * L} and I wish to partition the variation in body size with elevation into its two components L and r.

So in short, I need to split the variation in the dependent variable into its two collinear components and figure out which one is contributing most to the overall change?

I would have given example data, but I guess the question requires more conceptual clarification than anything. Any help is much appreciated (specifically if anyone could direct me to appropriate R function that can help me achieve this). Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. But if I want to answer the question "Change in body size with elevation is more due to change in body length or due to change in thorax width, given their differential contribution to calculation of body size?", how can I go about something like this? I think a bit of background might help - the organismal group of interest here is "moths", and since moths can generate heat using thoracic muscles, a higher contribution of thorax would support thermoregulation as a mechanism for higher observed body sizes at higher elevations.

Comment: Please give more details. What is "elevation" ? What exaclty is your linear regression model (please write the equation for the whole model) ?

Comment: I have 13 sampling locations each at a distance of 200 meters (in elevation). So my independent variable (_X_) here = 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000.....2600. Mean body size (_Y_) at an elevation is arithmetic mean for all individuals collected at that elevation. The regression of _Y_ ~ _X_ gives me _Y_ = 1.08 * 10^-4 * _X_ + 1.82. The _Y_ here, i.e. mean body size, is a non-linear function of two collinear variables - body length (_L_) and thorax width (_r) such that _Y_ = 1/3 * pi * r^2 * _L_; I want to quantify the relative contribution of each of these to the slope of the above equation.

Comment: In that case, this regression approach to the analysis of your data is doomed. 

You need to think carefully about your research question here.

You have regressed body size on sampling elevation, which is fixed by design, and that is perfectly fine.  But then you are asking how the *components* of body size (height and width) affect the sampling elevation, which makes no sense from a causal inference perspective.  What exactly is your research question ?

Comment: I want to be able to show (if at all) whether the change in body size with elevation, is primarily due to change in bodylength, or due to change in thorax width. I know it is going to be some combination of both, but I want to be able to answer which one of these two has a larger effect since they both will have different ecological interpretations.

Comment: You mention both size and mass. Are these the same ? Did you measure the actual size/mass, actual length and actual width of individual insects ?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I measured actual _bodylength_ and actual _thoraxwidth_ (for around 5000 insects) and modeled the resultant  _bodysize_ as volume of a cone (formula in the original post).  Scratch _bodymass_ for now, I don't want to add to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since body size/mass is not a linear combination of L and r, you cannot decompose a non-linear function of two variables into a sum of functions of each variable.  It's like trying to decompose the volume of a cylinder ($V = \pi \times r^{2} \times h$) into a sum of some function of radius and some function of height.  So while you were able to measure the linear dependence between body mass and elevation, computing linear dependence between those two components and elevation and comparing them, or comparing their relative contributions in a linear multiple regression, will not give you the answer you want.

Assuming L and r are always positive, you could take the log of both sides of the $body mass = 1/3 \times \pi \times r^2 \times L$ equation, which will give you  $log(body mass) = 1/3 \times \pi \times (2 \times  log(r)) + 1/3 \times \pi \times log(L)$, and then perform a different correlation or regression analysis of the relationship with elevation.  The drawback of this is it  will change the size of linear dependence between variables compared to when they were in linear form (maybe correlation will increase but it could decrease).  But with this transformation, body mass (its log) will be a linear combination of the logs of L and r and you could then measure and compare the relative contributions of L and r in a multiple regression of elevation on L and r.

There are different ways to measure relative contributions of predictors in a multiple regression.  Here are some links: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/350276/241093, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11951/241093, https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_determine_the_relative_contribution_of_predictors_in_multiple_regression_models.

Comment: These are good points but note also that in this case, the *dependent* variable in the regression is is the bodymass $\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 L$. The question is specifically asking how $L$ and $r$ affect the regression coefficient for the sampling elevation, which does not make any sense to me, since the sampling elevation is fixed by design.

Comment: You are right, sampling elevation is fixed by design (hence the independent variable in my regression). It is the variation in the dependent variable, with respect to the independent variable,  that I want to partition into it's constituents. Could you explain a little more what is the issue in the nature of my problem?

Comment: @Mansi see my further comment to the question itself

Comment: @RobertLong, right, but we could flip the variables and make elevation the dependent variable, as it won't affect regression output?

Comment: Aside from the causal inference objection, the research question is "*how does length and width affect the relationship between elevation /and/ size?*". If elevation is the sole DV, what regression parameters would answer that question ? ?

Comment: My thought was that since size is a function of length and width, then any linear dependence between size and elevation can also be examined as a linear regression with elevation as DV and length and width as IV's.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting ! (+1 btw) So you propose (ignoring non-linearity for now) `Elevation ~ length + width` and the relative contributions to $R^2$ or maybe the relative sizes of  the regression coefficients would answer the question ?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The central metric of interest for you is the $R^2$, which explains the share of variation in $y$ that is jointly explained by your regressors $X$. So adding one variable at a time and observe the change in $R^2$ will tell you about the respective contribution of each variable.

Comment: While this is correct in a general sense of linear regression, it turns out that this particular situation is more complex (see comments to the question itself)

Answer (score 0):

This is one round-about way to go about this. I will find the equation for the relationship between length and width (*log(width)* ~ *log(length)*). Then find the relationship between residual width (by sybtracting the regression coeffients from *log(width)* ~ *log(length)*) and elevation. If residual width is increasing with elevation, then I know that thorax width is contributing disproportionately more to the increasing body size with elevation. It does not answer my original post, but it solves the question using another approach.